# Как перезаписать переменную в цикле и сохранить ее значение после выхода из цикла?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть ассоциативный массив и несколько строк:

```
let fontWeight = new Map(
                [
                    ['Thin', "100"],
                    ['Light', "300"],
                    ['Regular', "400"],
                    ['Medium', "500"],
                    ['Bold', "700"],
                    ['Black', "900"]
                ]
            );
```

Так же в цикле у меня есть строка `fontWeightStr`. В этой строке находятся строки, которые беру из названий файлов со шрифтами. Если, например, есть файл `'Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf'`, то в `fontWeightStr` у меня строка `"Bold"`.

Мне нужно на каждой итерации заменить содержимое `fontWeightStr` соответствующим значением ассоциативного массива. Для этого организовал такой перебор:

```
let fontWeightStr = 'Bold' // Для примера, в программе значения получены из имен файлов со шрифтами.

for (let i in fontWeight.keys()) {
    let key = fontWeight.keys()[i]; // получаем ключ из массива
    if (key == fontWeightStr) {
       fontWeightStr = fontWeight.get(fontWeightStr); // меняем содержимое строки на значение из массива
       break; // прерываем перебор
       }
}
```

Но этот цикл не дает результата. В `fontWeightStr` по прежнему находится строка `"Bold"`, а должна быть строка `"700"`. Я думаю, при выходе из цикла локальное значение уничтожается. Как правильно перезаписать переменную в этом случае?

Comment: очень странное ты пытаешься сделать. Зачем тут цикл вообще, если по сути проверяешь наличие ключа в Map и затем берешь значение

Comment: проверить наличие ключа можно с помощью [`Map.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has)

Comment: @Grundy Файлов со шрифтами может быть много и в fontWeightStr могут быть разные строки.

Comment: Суть от этого не меняется. Ты по сути можешь заменить весь свой код на `fontWeight.get(fontWeightStr)` и ничего не поменяется.

Comment: @Grundy Да, я понял уже после того, как написал комментарий. Не знал про Map.has () Спасибо, так все работает.